# Algorithm to sense stroke rate of Rower

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-motion

I am trying to calculate when there is force or acceleration along the Y axis of the Acellerometer.

This is what my code looks like

```
-(void)outputAccelertionData:(CMAcceleration)acceleration
{

self.accY.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1fg",acceleration.y];
if(fabs(acceleration.y) < fabs(currentMaxAccelY))
{
        [self count];
}
currentMaxAccelY = acceleration.y;

}


- (void) count
{
    counter = counter + 1;
    self.countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter];   
}
```

This currently dosnt work it just consistantly starts counting upwards. what I was trying to achive is this.

New current max acceleration is reached (so effectivly higher than the previous total. as the acceleration slows i update current max to the new low variable then wait till it is triggered but a higher value.

Currently my code dosnt work.. any help fixing it or even improving the algorithum would be really helpful... this is the first time I have tried anything along these lines so any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: Okay, I think my if statment is now correct, updates currentMaxAccelY with new low value when acceleration beats CurrentMaxAccelY then I add to the counter... However its way to sensitive atm and is constantly counting.. I would like to know how to prevent this from being so sensitive so that it counts strokes better.

Comment: Have you tried putting in a minimum value for your acceleration? So you only pay attention to the acceleration if it is above a certain threshold?

Comment: No I have no tried that but its a very good idea... I will look into that now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at running your data through a low pass filter. You can see an example in Apple's AccelerometerGraph sample code. I think it will get you closer to what you need. I recently implemented something similar in a camera app for detecting handheld motion with decent results. A lot comes down to your thresholds and how sensitive they need to be.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I Just went over the sample code, unfortunatly most of those frameworks have been depricated and replaced with Core motion, However I still had a read and a play round and managed to get a real rudimentary counter working and had some fun with the graphs and output so overall I have still learnt a little. I think the filtering is going to be the hardest part of this stroke rate calculater.

Comment: No doubt. You can use the CoreMotion data as input for your filters. Given the nature of rowing, you're probably looking at a relatively sustained value over a low threshold on the pull, and a similar negative on the reset.